# Monitoring self-hosted DNS, counting DNS requests in a time period

Tags: internal-dns, dns-hosting, authoritative

I have a self-hosted authoritative DNS server, using MaraDNS. We're having smaller periods of unresponsiveness during peak times. I'm guessing because of this it has to do with MaraDNS not having enough resources.

I want to monitor how many DNS requests it's getting, I can't seem to find anything that would log numbers of requests for a time (just full requests which seems like overkill). See [maraDNS config reference, log_level](http://maradns.samiam.org/tutorial/man.mararc.html).

One thing I could do is:

`tcpdump -q -i en0 port 53 | grep <something?> | echo '1\n' > somefile_txt`

`tcpdump -q -i en0 port 53` would get incoming traffic I believe, `q` would keep the output to one line and simple. I don't know what the tcpdump will look like for getting a request. Then I'd just write 1's to a file and do a `cat somefile_txt | wc -l` to see how many requests came in.

Is there a better way? Is there other ways to monitor DNS systems with more granularity?

Thanks!

Comment: From my own experience, it sometimes helps to start looking at OS stats (such as `netstat -s`) and see if the system is complaining that applications are not keeping up with data rates.  Then I start looking at app settings, log levels, rate limits, etc.  Can you speculate the packets-per-second rate you are getting in peak times?